# Remove [HMR] logs in chrome devtools

Tags: regex, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-hmr

I have been trying to filter `[HMR] *` messages in devtools with these regex

- `/^(?!\[HMR\]).*$/`
- `/^(?!\[HMR\]).*$/gm`

[image]

However with these regex it did found the things I need, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OkGFkR/2). Images can be found below
Php flavor: [image]

Javascript flavor: [image]

Comment: You are matching [WDS] and the like because you are trying to find "not starting with HMR". I don't see nothing wrong here. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Simply use `-[HMR]`

Comment: Thank you man it works, @wOxxOm . But may i know why my regex doesnt work on devtool filter.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com

Comment: My guess is that you're using a RegEx pattern that is not fully supported in JavaScript. For example, in the RegEx testing tool that you took a screenshot of, you're using a PHP flavor of RegEx. Try using the JavaScript flavor, instead.

Comment: Hi @KayceBasques, I did try your suggestion but the outcome are still the same. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special Chrome filter syntax for removing lines like that:

```
-[HMR]
```

and

```
-[WDS]
```

This removes all lines matching `[HMR]` and `[WDS]` without using regex.

Comment: So there's no confusion, put those values into the expression field above the console. I initially was creating a Live Expression via clicking the eye icon. Oops!

Comment: Please can you suggest one you've used before?

Comment: What do you mean?